# how to apply lazy loading to nested modules in angular?

Tags: angular, components, lazy-loading

Our main website is taking very heavy loading time sometimes its not loading due to heavy bundle size. To reduce the loading time we are trying to apply lazy loading to the different modules under our website. We are having 150+ components written in angular 7. Many of these components are nested components. We are creating module for each component and applying lazy loading to the respective module.

But we are facing problem in applying lazy loading to nested components. For Example we have applied Lazy loading to Module A. In module A we are loading Component A. In Component A we are using  component B  and C. We are facing issue in applying lazy loading to Component B and Component C.

We want to create separate modules for Component B and Component C and load these modules in Module A. How should we proceed to it. Or do we have any other solutions to implement lazy loading to these nested components.

Comment: Why can't you use the same lazy loaded platform that you used for the module that contains A component for your new module that contains B and C component?

Comment: If you update your angular version to angular 9/10 you can use the ivy compiler. The ivy compiler lets you easily lazy load a component or a module without the need of a route etc.  Here is an article where you can see how easy it is: https://johnpapa.net/angular-9-lazy-loading-components/